# FFmpeg: apply audio/video fade-in on the first TS chunk, then "cat" all chunks produces a frame loss

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

this is my first post (*on video.stackexchange.com*).

I need some explanation regarding to re-encoding a **single** .ts chunk and then use `cat` command.

I'll explain my scenario.

I've a  lot of `.ts` chunks that all together create a smooth video. Tested.

To create a single video I use the classic linux `cat` command, and everything works a treat.

**BUT**

These "*lot of `.ts` chunks*" reside on a web-hosting where, obviously, it is not possible to install ffmpeg, **but I can use `cat`** command (through PHP's `shell_exec`).

---

**My goal** 
is to apply an audio/video fade-in on first chunk (and so far I've done it with `-vf "fade=t=in:st=0.1:d=1"` and `-af "afade=t=in:st=0.1:d=1"`) on my local machine and then, after uploaded the "faded chunk" on remote web-hosting, `cat` the faded chunk + remaing chunks.

---

**My actual results**

My concatenated-chunks-video has a frame-gap at the end of the "faded chunk" and the beginning of the next chunk. After this, plays smoothly.

---

**CLI**

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/first_chunk.ts -vf "fade=t=in:st=0.1:d=1, format=yuv420p" -af "afade=t=in:st=0.1:d=1" -c:v libx264 -b:v 5099.998K -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 -c:a aac -b:a 279000 -strict experimental -y /path/to/first_chunk_fade_in.ts

cat /path/to/first_chunk_fade_in.ts /path/to/2nd_chunk.ts /path/to/3rd_chunk.ts /path/to/4th_chunk.ts /path/to/5th_chunk.ts > /path/to/merged.ts
```

Note:

All `-c:v`, `-b:v`, `-profile:v`, `-level:v`, `-c:a`, `-b:a` values were recovered and / or calculated from the original chunk using `ffprobe`

---

Any ideas? Or do I have to re-encode the whole file?

Many thanks

Comment: Add -copyts and check.

Comment: I try immediately....

Comment: With -copyts I lose the fade

Comment: Instead of `st`, use the start frame and sample options instead.

Comment: same thing. Ok for fade but gap remains. I believe, however, that problem is not attributable to the video stream, but rather to the audio track. I explain to you. I open the merged file with VLC. 
Starting from the beginning of the stream, if I PLAY, there's the gap, but if I make a frame-by-frame (shortcut "e" on VLC), no gap occurs and everything runs smoothly. Since VLC does not handle audio on the frame-by-frame (the video becomes mute), I think it's the audio track "in some way" carries with it the video track trying to "put it in sync", creating this little hop in the junction point.

Comment: I also tried to disable the audio fade and leave the video track with `-c:a copy`.

What I'm sure of is that the audio track, once the chunk is encoded, doesn't start at 0 like the original chunk, but after a few ms

Comment: Explain what you mean by gap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92296/discussion-between-oscar-zarrus-and-gyan).